# How to make accordion get value from data base

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I had Accordion (Ajax Control) and I did it to get value from data base I did my code but it didnot get any value please any one help me

'
                                        Width="178" Height="115" Style="float: left; padding: 10px 10px 0 10px" />'>
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    Heading
                                                
                                                
                                                    '>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt = myData.Tables["News"];`

Accordion1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
Accordion1.DataBind();
}

<cc1:accordion id="Accordion1" runat="server" selectedindex="0" fadetransitions="false" framespersecond="40" transitionduration="250" autosize="None">
<headertemplate>
<%# Eval("NewsCaption") %>
<%# Eval("NewsDate") %>
</headertemplate>
<contenttemplate>
<%# Eval("NewsBody") %>
</contenttemplate>